# Rails, start timer server side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timer

I want to make a time keeping app in rails that will keep track of users times. I am wondering how can someone start a timer when a use pushes a button, but once they exit the browser, that timer will always keep running until the user comes back and clicks stop on the timer.
Is there a gem that will allow you to do this? or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: It is a very simple task. All you need to do is to store time the button was pressed in the session and display on the screen how many seconds ago it was.

Comment: doesn't the session get removed if they close out of the browser though?

Comment: Rails session depends on the cookie being present on the customer browser. Cookies are not removed when the browser closes, they are only removed when they expires. You can also set the cookie to never expire.

Comment: but a customer can clear cookies on browser so that is not very reliable to store in cookies, is it?

Comment: That's unfortunately the only option you have, web is stateless and cookies are the only way to change it. You can try to store time against user IP address, but it is not certain as well. If the button is available without login system, there is not much more you can do.

Comment: ok thank you for the advice. I needed someone to pick their brain.